# Creating a 2-D array that would randomize the objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to create a 2-D array that is a 4x4 and I have 8 different classes which I want to randomize the positions they are input into the 2-D array whenever the program is run. I understand the concept of randomizing or shuffling numbers, however when it comes to classes I have no idea. I was going to initialize it manually but would like to see if anyone would know how to randomize those positions.

Edit:
I should have clarified, I want to strictly use arrays but also maybe I am just confused.
For example if I were to do it manually I have:

```
    board = new CardGame[4][4];

    board[0][0] = new Card1();
    board[0][1] = new Card1();
    board[0][2] = new Card2();
    board[0][3] = new Card2();  
    board[1][0] = new Card3();
    board[1][1] = new Card3();
    board[1][2] = new Card4();
    board[1][3] = new Card4();
    board[2][0] = new Card5();
    board[2][1] = new Card5();
    board[2][2] = new Card6();
    board[2][3] = new Card6();  
    board[3][0] = new Card7();
    board[3][1] = new Card7();
    board[3][2] = new Card8();
    board[3][3] = new Card8();
```

I'm just confused how I would go about implementing it to be random.

Comment: Do you require there to be a fixed amount of objects of each of you classes (2 each in your example)?

Comment: Yes I do, so with the 8 classes that appear twice, i wish to randomize their positions, I only know how to manually put their positions

Comment: @KoreanGhost Have updated my answer to an Array only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the updated question, you can use this method with your code.

```
// Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
static void shuffleArray(CardGame[] ar)
{
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
    // Simple swap
    CardGame a = ar[index];
    ar[index] = ar[i];
    ar[i] = a;
  }
}
```

Called via:

```
shuffleArray(board[0]);
shuffleArray(board[1]);
shuffleArray(board[2]);
shuffleArray(board[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your 8 objects in a List, choose a random number 0 <= x < 8 and pick that class in the list. Pick one random object and put it in your 2-D array until you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's a 4x4 Array, you know that its positions are between `[0][0]` and `[3][3]`.

You could get 2 random Numbers between 0 and 3 for each Object, say, `x` and `y`. After that, check if there is already an Object in position `[x][y]` in the array, and if not, place it there. If there is already an Object, you could re-generate a new random Number pair and check that one.

Comment: This method could, in theory, loop forever. You're looking for 16 unique pairs, generating the pairs randomly could lead to never hitting all 16.

Comment: As I understood the original question (before the edit), (s)he only tried to place 8 objects in the 16 positions, which led me to conclude this would be enough. Also I would challange the "never" part, but well..

Comment: Fair. Also: "could lead to never" :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating random (x,y)-Positions and putting the objects into the respective array cells might cause collisions - and just re-generating new coordinates when the chosen ones are already occupied is not so nice from a theoretical point of view, because it will not necessarily terminate. If the array size is that small, this may not be an issue, but I'd still rather use another strategy

(EDIT: Changed according to the updated question)

E.g. filling a list with the cards, then `Collections#shuffle` this list, and place it into the array row by row.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


class Card{}
class Card1 extends Card{}
class Card2 extends Card{}
class Card3 extends Card{}
class Card4 extends Card{}
class Card5 extends Card{}
class Card6 extends Card{}
class Card7 extends Card{}
class Card8 extends Card{}
public class CardShuffle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Card[][] board = new Card[4][4];

        List<Card> list = new ArrayList<Card>();
        list.add(new Card1());
        list.add(new Card1());
        list.add(new Card2());
        list.add(new Card2());
        list.add(new Card3());
        list.add(new Card3());
        list.add(new Card4());
        list.add(new Card4());
        list.add(new Card5());
        list.add(new Card5());
        list.add(new Card6());
        list.add(new Card6());
        list.add(new Card7());
        list.add(new Card7());
        list.add(new Card8());
        list.add(new Card8());
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        fill(board, list);
    }

    private static void fill(Card board[][], List<Card> list)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<board.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++)
            {
                board[i][j] = list.get(index);
                index++;
                if (index >= list.size())
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```